# With or without 'to'

Tags: grammar, sentence, flow

Should it be 'the place we went last night' or 'the place we went to last night'?

I feel like if I swap 'restaurant' in for 'place', I'd definitely include the preposition 'to'. But with 'place', you have sayings like 'It's always the last place you look.' (used without preposition at) 'This is the place to go.' (without preposition to after go)
Can 'place' alone function as an adverbial of location much like 'the day' as in 'the day I graduated', except 'the day' functions as an adverbial of time.

Which one do you see people more likely to say in spoken English, 'the place we went to last night' or 'the place we went last night'?

Could that have something to do with the flow and rhythmn of sentences too?
I feel like 'the place we went to last night' flows better than without 'to', but if you have a couple more syllables in the sentence, leaving out 'to' would be preferable as in 'the place we used to go on Saturdays'. What do you think?

Comment: I think it mostly depends on the verb. You "go to" a place, but you "look in" a place.

Comment: @Barmar That's true but both 'to' and 'in' are prepositions. In "the place we went last night" there is no preposition at all. People often say that but I would say that it a case of the preposition being suppressed rather than it's being a different construction.

Comment: In many cases both forms are acceptable, although one is more common and idiomatic. E.g. "last place in which you look" is a possibility.

Comment: A common rule is that if you can leave out the preposition, people usually will. English is a lazy language.

Comment: _Go_ and _come_, and their causative relations _take_ and _bring_, are special verbs with special grammar. They occur in many idioms and fixed phrases, most of which use prepositions. Those prepositions don't have any independent meaning; like articles, auxiliary verbs, and the _-'s_ suffix on possessives, they're part of the mechanics of grammar. In this case, the destination can be optionally named without _to_ with _go_ and _come_, just as articles can be deleted with certain nouns (_home, school, college, hospital_). That means you get a choice, and there isn't any difference in meaning.

Comment: Be "to" or not be "to", that is the question!

Answer (score 0):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> *Go* and *come*, and their causative relations *take* and *bring*, are special verbs with special grammar. They occur in many idioms and fixed phrases, most of which use prepositions. Those prepositions don't have any independent meaning; like articles, auxiliary verbs, and the *-'s* suffix on possessives, they're part of the mechanics of grammar. In this case, the destination can be optionally named without *to* with *go* and *come*, just as articles can be deleted with certain nouns (*home, school, college, hospital*). That means you get a choice, and there isn't any difference in meaning.